# Interface implementation access modifier not as expected

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I came across this example of an interface implementation which I can't my head around, with the text not having any reasoning for the the answer so hopefully someone on here can lend a hand.

Given the interface

```
interface Flyer{
   void takeOff();
   boolean land();
}
```

then suppose I have an implementation as follows

```
class Aeroplane implements Flyer{
   public void takeOff(){
   ...
   }
   //insert code here
       return true;
   }  
}
```

The code to insert that I am given is 
`public boolean land(){` and it states that the following is INCORRECT `boolean land(){`

Why do I need to have the `public` when the interface has defined the method as `package-private`, surely `boolean land(){` should implement the interface, or have I missed something?

Comment: Void isn't boolean. Also, interfaces are implicitly public, that's the point of an interface.

Comment: sorry thats my mistake... edited..

Comment: "the interface has defined the method as package-private". Methods declared in interfaces are public by definition. No way around it.

Comment: ahhh... that makes sense now, sneaky...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"the interface has defined the method as package-private"*

All methods declared in interfaces are public by definition. There is no way around this.

This

```
interface Flyer{
   void takeOff();
   boolean land();
}
```

is equivalent to this

```
interface Flyer{
   public void takeOff();
   public boolean land();
}
```

This is **illegal**:

```
interface Flyer{
   private void takeOff();
   private boolean land();
}
```

as is this:

```
interface Flyer{
   protected void takeOff();
   protected boolean land();
}
```

Neither will compile.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. That's why I deleted my comment, hoping you wouldn't see it. Your edit makes it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Interface does not define method as a package-private. All methods declared by interface are `public`. You are confusing with the default access modifier. It is indeed package-private for classes but `public` for interfaces. So, definition:

```
interface Flyer{
   void takeOff();
   void land();
}
```

is absolutely equivalent to

```
interface Flyer{
   public void takeOff();
   public void land();
}
```